# How to write a custom query in Wordpress that fetches custom post types filtered by a dynamic taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

**Introduction**

I'm a graphic designer that knows nothing about PHP, but I need to get my hands dirty in this particular situation and I need help from the coding gods.
I've been struggling with this problem quite a bit, reading about it and trying stuff, but I'm probably too noob to figure it out.

**Toolkit**

I have a Wordpress site and I'm  using Elementor Pro to build it.
I'm using the plugins "CPT-UI" to have my own custom post types, and "CPT-onomies" to be able to use a CPT as a taxonomy for another CPT.
From Elementor I can call a custom query if I'm able to write it within the "Snippets" plugin.

**The circumstances**

That said, I'll describe exactly what's going on:
I have a "Projects" CPT and a "Designs" CPT, both are CPTs. At the same time, "Projects" is a taxonomy related to "Designs", this means that I can group many designs that belongs to the same big "Project".
For example, if I've designed Coca-Cola's logo and also designed business cards with that logo, then both designs would be grouped into the taxonomy (which is also a CPT) called "New Coca Identity".
So from within the "New Coca Identity" page (which is actually a dynamic template applied to all "Projects") I can fetch all designs which have the current loop id ("New Coca Identity" in this case) assigned as their taxonomy.

**Should be something like this (I believe)**

So this is what I came up with...

```html
// Create the action to call this query from Elementor
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query/projects_designs_query', function($query)
{

// Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

// If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

// Append our meta query
    $tax_query[] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'projects',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => 'HERE SHOULD BE THE DYNAMIC ID I GUESS',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it through! I'll share how I did in case some other person lacking the php knowledge like me lands in the same spot.

```
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query/projects_designs_query', function($query)
{

$post_id = get_the_ID();

$meta_query[] = [
            'post_type' => 'designs',
            'taxonomy' => 'projects',
            'value' => $post_id,
            'compare' => 'in',
];
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

What this achieves is firstly getting the ID of the current post in the loop (which in my case is a Project custom post type). Then it gets all the post (with custom post type Design) that belong to the same project (the current post).